# NxBRE rule engine, call method with passing objects as arguments

Tags: nxbre

I am currently trying to work with NxBRE rule engine https://github.com/ddossot/NxBRE

What I am trying to do is to create a rule in .XBRE file in which I call a method in my .CS file with passing an object as argument(not primitive type like integer,string...).

I tried this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuXDf.png)

my method is testChild and it's in FlowEngineExample.Program class, and takes as argument an object of type FlowEngineExample.Problem that i passed to the rule Context with ID Problem. But this doesn't work since argument only accept types like Integer,string ...

What do i have to do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
<Argument valueId="Problem"/>
```

to provide a reference to the context ID `Problem`.

Comment: thank you!! i didn't know that i can delete the type attribute of Argument element. it works now.